# Render Output name order

Tags: rendering, output

When I render the order of the files are first all the frames 1, next the 2 and that, I want the name of the camera be on first of all for separate all by camera

`(cameraview)name(frame).png`
How I can do it like that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run this script in blender text editor:

```
import bpy

def name_set(scene):
    scene.render.filepath = 'path-to-the-file' + scene.camera.name+'_name_####.png'

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(name_set)
```

Comment: only rename the first camara multiview  when render, and only render on the (C:) cant give custom path now hehehe

Comment: i think is posible make work if you edit the code for refresh every time a imagen is rendered

Comment: Hm... Try `bpy.app.handlers.render_init` or `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post`  or `bpy.app.handlers.render_write` then

Comment: still same, only print the first camara on rendering, and others names dont get change

Comment: `frame_change_pre` works for me with camera markers.

Comment: ahhh camara market but i using camara multi-view, i rendering 4 camaras on same time XD

Comment: my bad i dint say is it multi-view camara, you can make a script for work on multi-view camara? and sorry for molest you friend, you are my god now

Comment: A, I see now. Some add-on is responsible for managing file names. I don't know about this add-on